# Can I access my Stack Overflow accounts without external JavaScript?

Tags: support, login

I can log in with OpenID, but I am having problems logging out. Whenever I open Stack Overflow, a message appears on the top of my screen saying:

> Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load

I guess this is due to restrictions in my office network. Can I access my Stack Overflow accounts without external JavaScript? Is there any basic HTML version of Stack Overflow that can be used in these circumstances?

Comment: (For a list of other domains, see also [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need))

Comment: Given you have *"problems logging in **and** logging out"*: so you actually can log in?

Comment: yes i was able to log in with open Id but couldn't log out.I'll appreciate if i am able to log in and out **normally**.

Answer (score 1):

I'd bet the blocked javascript in this case is the "clear global login" script from stackauth.com.

All it does is remove a key from localStorage under the stackauth.com domain.  You can do that manually, if you want.

Alternatively, you can disable global auth altogether by blocking the stackauth.com domain, or disabling javascript.  Neither experience is stellar, honestly, but it's what a "HTML-only" version of Stack Overflow would be doing so... yeah.

Comment: Hmm no, that message is the "there's no jQuery" warning.

Comment: [So I'm not crazy after all](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16829/how-to-turn-on-load-external-javascript-on-the-galaxy-nexus)